# jQuery - preventDefault stops working after i add more code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with an image gallery. when I click on a photo, I would like nothing to happen. I used this code to accomplish that >>>

```
$('#imageGallery a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();     });
```

but all of a sudden, if I add this top line....

```
var $overlay = $("<div id = "overlay"></div>");

$('#imageGallery a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
   });
```

...My code no longer works and the photo that I click goes to another page. Is there something I'm not doing or could this be a browser issue?

Comment: You need to use single quotes inside double quotes: `var $overlay = $("<div id = 'overlay'></div>");`

Comment: Try to use one of the patterns in my answer to prevent similar typos in the future. I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to let jQuery create HTML elements for you. You had some typos in what you tried that resulted in malformed code. These are some methods of creating an element that are in decreasing order of human-error proneness:

Try using

```
var $overlay = $("<div id = 'overlay'></div>");
```

or

```
var $overlay = $("<div id = \"overlay\"></div>");
```

or

```
var $overlay = $("<div/>", {id: "overlay"});
```

or

```
var $overlay = $('<div/>').attr("id", "overlay");
```

to create new elements in the future.